# Null safe "between" Spark operator

Tags: scala, apache-spark

TL;DR: Is there a null safe `between` operator in Spark?

---

I know about `<=>`, but that gets a bit verbose and less readable when I have to perform a `between` operation.

Giving a bit of context, I have a score in table A, and score upper and lower limits in table B. I need to join them when the score in table A is between score limits in table B. Thing is, when score on table A is null, it should be compared to null upper and lower limits in table B.

A bit of code to clarify:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

/* Helper function to generate DataFrames the verbose way, which was
chosen because I wasn't able to mock these DataFrames containing null
values in numeric columns without specifying the schema - Scala was 
sending the data as "AnyVal", and Spark wasn't happy about it */


def generateDataFrame(data: List[Row], schema: List[StructField]): DataFrame = {
  spark.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize(data),
    StructType(schema)
  )
}


/************************* DataFrame mocking *********************/
val tableASchema = List(
  StructField("player", StringType), 
  StructField("score", DoubleType)
)
val tableAData = List(
  Row("player1", 450.0),
  Row("player2", null)
)
val tableA = generateDataFrame(tableAData, tableASchema)

val tableBSchema = List(
  StructField("lower_limit", IntegerType),
  StructField("upper_limit", IntegerType),
  StructField("band", StringType)
)
val tableBData = List(
  Row(null, null, "noScore"),
  Row(400, 500, "400-500")
)
val tableB = generateDataFrame(tableBData, tableBSchema)


/************************* Join - the problem itself *********************/
val currentSolution = tableA.join(
  tableB, 
  when($"score".isNull, $"score" <=> $"lower_limit" and $"score" <=> $"upper_limit")
  .otherwise($"score" between($"lower_limit", $"upper_limit")),
  "left"
)

val intendedSolution = tableA.join(
  tableB, 
  $"score" safeBetween($"lower_limit", $"upper_limit")
  "left"
)
```

The difference between intended and current is readability only. Is there such a method as safeBetween?

Comment: I think you can implicit to create safeBetween on column object in an elegant manner.

Comment: I take that as suggesting there is no such a thing already built-in Spark, right?
I agree, but I was hoping not having to get my hands dirty on that matter :(

Comment: `when score on table A is null, it should be compared to null upper and lower limits in table B`, I don't really get what that should yield, how to compare `null` with `null`?

Comment: `null` equals `null`, so the records should match. Just how it happens when using `<=>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no `safeBetween`, but its easy to define that on you own. Note that I also refactored the data generation:

```
import spark.implicits._

val tableA = List(
  ("player1", Some(450.0)),
  ("player2", None)
).toDF("player","score")

val tableB = List(
  (None, None, "noScore"),
  (Some(400), Some(500), "400-500")
).toDF("lower_limit","upper_limit","band")

implicit class ColumnExt(c:Column) {
   def safeBetween(c1: Column,c2: Column) = coalesce(c between(c1,c2),c.isNull and c1.isNull and c2.isNull)
}


val solution: DataFrame = tableA.join(
  tableB,
  $"score" safeBetween($"lower_limit",$"upper_limit"),
  "left"
)
```

Comment: Well, then, sir, I didn't use that way to generate the DataFrame because of the `null`, but then you slap my face with a very basic Scala feature that I forgot, `Option`. 

Sadly, there is no such an operator built-in, as was my expectation. But, hell yeah, this answers the question alright.